# My htaccess redirects with regex aren't working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have the following redirect in my htaccess:

Redirect 301  "^/city/(.*)-north-carolina$"  "https://example.com/US/NC/$1-north-carolina-hotels.php"

When I enter example.com/city/asheville-north-carolina I don't get the redirect like I should.  Something wrong with my syntax or does something need to happen with RewriteCond?

I've tried various version of the syntax, nothing

Comment: The documentation of the apache modules is, as typical for OpenSource software, of _excellent_ quality and comes with great examples. It is well worth taking a look into it when you have such tasks at hand.

Answer (score 1):

The `Redirect` directive only takes a static URL as input.

To solve it, either :

- Replace `Redirect` by [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) :

  ```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/city/(.*)-north-carolina$ https://example.com/US/NC/$1-north-carolina-hotels.php
  ```

  Here, `RedirectMatch` will receive the leading slash of the URL.

Or

- Use a [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) :

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^city/(.*)-north-carolina$ https://example.com/US/NC/$1-north-carolina-hotels.php [R=301,L]
  ```

  In this case, `RewriteRule` receives the path without the leading slash.